# How to Filter Data Based off Cell Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to filter my data based off of a cell value. My data will be a large range for 12 months. So far I am able to filter only one month, I cannot figure out how to filter all 12 months based off my cell value. Here is the formula I am using `=INDEX(B6:B25,MATCH(B50,B4:AP4,0))` I have included a link to my file for better clarification. My MATCH cell is `$B$1` and my formula is placed in cell `$B$2`

Here's [my link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3kb1e6kmftbkys/sample%20file.xlsx?dl=0)

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Do you try the advanced filter?

Comment: Adding a link to the worksheet is very useful, but you **must** also include a screenshot. If the link breaks/file is deleted (like has happened), then the question may become useless/poor quality (as is the case here given that the only answer doesn't use your original data/cells). Note that, unlike what is stated in that answer, it *is* possible to do whatever it is your are trying to do with a single formula, without using any helper cells.

Comment: It looks like the dropbox link is dead.  Without that and a screenshot, the question isn't clear enough to be helpful to other readers (which is kind of the purpose of the site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've constructed this solution on the basis of the example shown in attached Screen Shot.**

*In your formula `=INDEX(B6:B25,MATCH(B50,B4:AP4,0))` you are trying to match Months are in different Row intervals is not looking possible to accommodate with a single Formula.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write Month's Name in Cell `F46`, `G46` & `H46`.
- Write this Formula in Cell `F47` & fill it Right.

  `=INDEX($A$47:$A$59,MATCH(F46,$A$46:$A$59,0))`

**Note:**

- This Formula will return only the First match value for every Month.
- You need to extend the Lits of Months in Row `46` as well as the Formula in Row `47`.

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: thank you! Your formula does what I needed to do!

Comment: @JoseCortez, glad to help you plzz keep asking ☺

Comment: Just write your concern Y down voted ??

Comment: sorry i did not downvote your answer

Comment: it's okay @JoseCortez,, since the post got Down vote then I'm eager to learn the reason to improve it ☺